# Activity destroyed before onActivtyResult Android

Tags: android

Ok, I'm startActivityForResult to take a picture and save it to storage, to the file that I have already specified (its path).

I ran to this strange thing that I didn't know about -

When you start activity for result in one orientation, and then switch the orientation when finishing with other activity, since orientation of your activity has changed, onDestroy is called and then onCreate, onStart, and after all that onActivityResult, which means that you cannot do something when you get back to activity if you need some data that you would persist in onSaveInstanceState.

Am I correct and why is that so?

The order how functions are called in the first activity when the second activity finishes is

- Destroy
- Create
- Start
- ActivityResult

Isn't it more reasonable to be

- ActivityResult
- Pause
- SaveInstanceState
- Stop
- Destroy
- Create

So, if there's no use to save in onSaveInstanceState, should I do it in onPause? And what is the best way to do it?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState()` should be called, as should `onPause()` and `onResume()`, before `onDestroy()`, in your first set of bullets.

Comment: Ok, I agree, but this is what happens after you finish with the second activity, and when it goes back to first one that has changed orientation in the meanwhile. I have edited the question.

Comment: And that's why using Fragments and retaining the instance state are so popular.

Comment: @Zhuinden ok, how do you suggest that it should be done? I'm new to Android development, so I haven't got all the concepts already, but have a strong feeling that problems are yet to come when I start with communication with server and background threads. :D I'm also targeting from Android 2.2, and if I understood well, fragments are far ahead (in time) for it. Is it worth investing time for fragments and support, or is there a way all to function normally with Activities? Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: "but this is what happens after you finish with the second activity" -- that is because they are called before the camera activity appears on the screen. They are definitely called, and you can use them as you would in any other case. "fragments are far ahead (in time) for it" -- a fragments backport is in the Android Support package and has been there for ~3 years.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for pointing that out for me, I haven't thought that the onDestroy is actually following the previous onStop. And I will definitely spend some time on fragments.